# Why do librosa lpc coefficients return a wrong-fixed-gain envelope?

Tags: python, librosa

I'm investigating the use of lpc coefficients for spectral modulation purposes but noticed a incoherence with what I guess it is a more correct spectral envelope estimation.

1. **What I guess** (and you guys maybe can reveal me on this): the spectral envelope should barely touch the spectrum in its higher peaks, as a generic envelope does for a generic curve (it kind of contains the curve itself);
2. **What I get from librosa**: the spectral envelope is far above the spectrum, following the variance of it but not the absolute value

For this reason I provided to you a code that takes a 1 second segment from a vocalization audio file and plots spectrum, envelope and auto-fixed envelope (this latter it's more similar to what I think it should be). Please look at the generated picture also.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import freqz
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq
from librosa import lpc
import soundfile as sf

plt.style.use('ggplot')

# defining audio path ----------------------------------------------
path = '...'

# reading data and managing multichannel (need a monophonic signal) -----------------
audio, sr = sf.read(path)  # importing wave file

# if two channels are found just compress them in one -----------------
if audio.ndim != 1:
    audio = audio.mean(axis=1)

# generating time related array for slicing -----------------
time = np.arange(audio.size) / sr

# getting the 1 second signal from slicing -----------------
signal = audio[(time >= 8) & (time < 9)]

# computing spectrum for plotting purposes -----------------
frequency = fftfreq(signal.size, 1 / sr)  # frequency related array
spectrum = np.abs(fft(signal)[frequency >= 0])  # taking just positive frequency for graphical purposes
frequency = frequency[frequency >= 0]  # we don't need negative frequencies anymore

# computing lpc analysis ----------------------------
a = lpc(signal, 16)  # estimating envelope filter's coefficients with standard reasonable values
b = np.hstack([[0], -1 * a[1:]])  # following librosa's documentation (but it works also in other ways)

# drawing the envelope ------------------------------
_, envelope = freqz(b, a, worN=signal.size // 2, whole=False, fs=sr)
envelope = np.abs(envelope)  # we just need the magnitude of what is returned as a complex array above

# converting in dBFS scale: 20 * log10(item) -----------------
spectrum_db = 20 * np.log10(spectrum)
envelope_db = 20 * np.log10(envelope)

# auto fixing the envelope's gain according to a generic rule based on spectrum's maximum value -----------------
max_freq_bin = np.argmax(spectrum_db)
gain = envelope_db[max_freq_bin] - spectrum_db[max_freq_bin]
envelope_db_fixed = envelope_db - gain

# plotting stuff -----------------
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
axs[0].plot(np.arange(signal.size) / sr, signal)
axs[0].set_title("Time view")
axs[0].set_ylabel("Amplitude [auS]")
axs[0].set_xlabel("Time [s]")
axs[1].plot(frequency, spectrum_db, label='original spectrum')
axs[1].plot(frequency, envelope_db, label='estimated envelope')
axs[1].plot(frequency, envelope_db_fixed, label='estimated envelope (fixed gain)')
axs[1].set_title("Frequency view")
axs[1].set_ylabel("Magnitude [dbFS]")
axs[1].set_xlabel("Frequency [Hz]")
axs[1].set_xscale('symlog')
axs[1].legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: A spectral estimation comprising direct spectrum computation plus spectral enevelope estimation with both the original version from librosa + freqz and a fixed version from me (just to give the idea)]
Does anyone know why I get a "spectral offset"?

NOTE: I didn't apply any scale factor to the various item, keeping the original scale of the signal and the scipy fft function, as well as the scipy freqz scale for envelope drawing